# Pushing std_logic_vector to variable

Tags: variables, vhdl

I'm trying to push two `std_logic_vector`s to to the variables `a` and `b` in the function `divide`.
Now, the problem is that the variable `b` won't be written.
But variable `a` will be written, which is coded the same way as `b`.

I received the following error message:

> used initial value expression for variable "b1" because variable was never assigned a value

This is the function call:

```
s_ratio <= divide((to_unsigned(0,N_CUM-4) & unsigned(hold_ratio(7 downto 4))) , (to_unsigned(0,N_CUM-4) & unsigned(hold_ratio(3 downto 0))));
```

And this is the function with the variable `b` in line 3.

```
function  divide  (a : UNSIGNED; b : UNSIGNED) return UNSIGNED is
  variable a1 : unsigned(a'length-1 downto 0):=a;
  variable b1 : unsigned(b'length-1 downto 0):=b;
  variable p1 : unsigned(b'length downto 0):= (others => '0');
  variable i : integer:=0;
begin
  for i in 0 to b'length-1 loop
    p1(b'length-1 downto 1) := p1(b'length-2 downto 0);
    p1(0) := a1(a'length-1);
    a1(a'length-1 downto 1) := a1(a'length-2 downto 0);
    p1 := p1-b1;
    if(p1(b'length-1) ='1') then
      a1(0) :='0';
      p1 := p1+b1;
    else
      a1(0) :='1';
    end if;
  end loop;
  return a1;

end divide;
```

Comment: What happens if you assign the initial value on the first two lines after `begin` instead of at the declaration of the variable?

Comment: The **error** message is right, you never assigned `b1`, it has an initial value, but no assignments. However, are you sure it is an error resulting in failure? I feel that what you describe is more likely to be a synthesis warning than failure... What tool are you using? How did you come to the conclusion that "[...] the variable b won't be written. But variable a will be written [...]"

Comment: Error message or warning?  Genning up a test bench for your assignment and function actually simulates.  What tool, as @Jonathan asks?

Comment: You're right, it's a synthesis warning and I'm using QuartusII. @ Jonathan Drolet: because I tested it on board.